# How do we assign value of EMF to a cell?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-circuits, potential, voltage, batteries

There are cells of different emfs like 1.5 volts, 2 volts etc. My concern is when we can not calculate the individual potential of any plate, or the potential difference between the plates by any formula.

How do we assign the values of emf of a cell?

Is it done experimentally by calculating the heat energy developed, by connecting it through a resistor, or is it done using Ohm's law $V=IR$ ?

Comment: You can measure it with a voltmeter.

Comment: Look up the Nernst equation.

Comment: can u give me a link on the same,thanks.

Comment: You can look up the Nernst equation in wikipedia and many other places. Here is a simple example where I used it: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/137102/79678. If your concern is simply *measurement*, then the answers already posted discuss that.

Answer (score 1):

In the old days, we usually used Ohm's law, making a voltmeter from a resistor in series with an analog current meter, magnetically deflecting a needle in front of a scale.

Voltmeters these days are more complicated. Most commonly, the input senses the voltage electrostatically using a MOSFET, while downstream circuitry uses a combination of techniques to convert the sense voltage to a digital number.

Comment: so its done experimentally ?

Comment: @sachin There is a body of theory https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_electrode_potential. But, in practice, with a cell on the bench in front of you, you reach for a voltmeter.

Comment: yes,its a good theory, probably these all things are not yet clear by scientists,so we can not argue much using mathematical equations or by asking any reverse question to an existing theory.

Answer (score 0):

The cell or battery EMF is the potential difference (voltage) across the battery terminals when there is no current being delivered by the battery to an external circuit. This is sometimes referred to as the "no load voltage".

To determine it precisely by measurement you would need to use a voltmeter whose input impedance is theoretically infinite, meaning, a voltmeter that draws virtually no current from the battery. I am not aware of any such voltmeter.

However, a highly accurate EMF can be determined by using a voltmeter having input impedance much much greater than the internal resistance of the battery or cell.

Hope this helps.